# How do I change the infoWindow property on Google Maps api in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, react-google-maps

I am a student studying `React`, and have been using the `@react-google-maps/api` package. While using Google Maps API, I found something called `infoWindowOptions`.

My goal is to change the UI to make it look good for the user.
However, I ran into some problems and was unable to get options to work with the `infoWindow`.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  InfoWindow,
  Marker,
  LoadScript,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

function Map() {
  const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(null);
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);

  const containerStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  };

  const success = (position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    setCurrentPosition({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
  };

  const error = () => {
    console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
  };

  const getCurrentLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentLocation();
  }, []);

  const infoWindowOptions = {
    backgroundColor: "purple",
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={apiKey}>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={currentPosition}
        zoom={13}
      >
        {currentPosition && <Marker position={currentPosition} />}
        {selectedMarker && (
          <InfoWindow
            options={infoWindowOptions}
            position={selectedMarker.position}
            onCloseClick={() => setSelectedMarker(null)}
          />
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

I tried to set the background color of the `infoWindow` as shown below; and was unsuccessful.

```
const infoWindowOptions = {
    backgroundColor: "purple",
  };
```

```
const infoWindowOptions = {
  options: {
    backgroundColor: "purple",
  },
};
```

Lastly, I tried to change the content in the `infoWindowOption`, but that did not work either.

I'm not sure what the problem is.. can anyone advise and help me out? Thank you!